# Get value by KeyPath<Object, Value>

Tags: swift, generics, key-value-observing, keypaths

I try get value by `KeyPath<Object, Value>` like this

```
func myFunc<Object: NSObject, Value>(in object: Object, for keyPath: KeyPath<Object, Value>) {
    let value = object[keyPath: keyPath]
    debugPrint(value, type(of: value)) // correct printing value
    print("nil? = ", value == nil) // always fail ??
    print("notNil? = ", value != nil) // always notNil ??
}
```

I need compare it `value` with `nil`
but I get very strange results in console, my check always have `notNil` result

example for

```
var test1: String! = "test"
myObservation.myFunc(in: self, for: \.test1)
```

> console output:
>
> test Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional
>
> nil? =  false
>
> notNil? =  true

example for

```
var test2: String? = nil
myObservation.myFunc(in: self, for: \.test2)
```

> console output:
>
> nil Swift.Optional
>
> nil? =  false // ???
>
> notNil? =  true

How I can compare my `value` with nil?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I get `none Optional<UIView>\n nil? =  true\n notNil? =  false`

Comment: you get value as `let value = object[keyPath: keyPath]` where keyPath is `KeyPath<Object, Value>` by KVO?

Comment: You have to be careful with assigning `weak` properties to constants, since by their nature they are mutable. Otherwise you could use the
`if let variableName = abc { 
    // variableName will be abc, unwrapped
} else {
    // abc is nil
}` statement

Comment: `weak` does not matter for this case

Comment: What you've written here doesn't really make sense. `Value` is not an optional type, so why do you expect to compare it to nil? Did you mean `KeyPath<Object, Value?>`? Do you know that the type returned will be optional? Creating `String!` types tends to greatly complicate your code. Why is it `String!` rather than `String` or `String?`?

Comment: this is `/// A key path from a specific root type to a specific resulting value type.
public class KeyPath<Root, Value> : PartialKeyPath<Root> {
}`

Comment: Right, but `Value` can be any type at all. You can't apply `==` to an arbitrary type. At a minimum it must be `Equatable`, and in order to compare it to `nil` it must be `NilLiteralConvertible`. In practice, this requires that `Value` be Optional, but your code doesn't require that. So it can't apply `== nil`. If you want to require that it be Optional, then you need to say so using `KeyPath<Object, Value?>` to indicate that the subscript will return an Optional.

Comment: It's unclear what you'd want this code to do (and the `String!` definitely is making things much more complicated then it needs to be). As a rule, Swift does not use introspection; it expects you to know the types of things at compile time.

Comment: =) sorry but can not be `KeyPath<Object, Value?>` it is wrong